# Умножить значении колонки в зависимости от значение строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть данные где суммы указаны в валютах USD, RUB. 
Мне необходимо с конвертировать значение этого столбца в национальную валюту и записать полученное число в отдельный столбец.

**Пример фрейма**:

Столбец `NAM_CCY_SHORT` содержит записи тип валюты -  `USD, RUB и TJS` и столбец `AMT_FACE_VALUE`

```
    NAM_CCY_SHORT   AMT_FACE_VALUE
0   TJS             12000.0
1   USD             5000.0
2   TJS             2000.0
3   USD             2500.0
4   TJS             8000.0
```

Необходимо в зависимости от значения столбца `NAM_CCY_SHORT` выполнить умножение значение столбца `AMT_FACE_VALUE` на число курса валют и записать в отдельный столбец `СONVERTED`

Comment: Столбцы это находятся в одном фрейме

Comment: курс валют будет просто указываться вручную, к примеру если строка = USD то значение 'AMT_FACE_VALUE ' * 10,2

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [3]: xchg_rates = dict(TJS=1, USD=10.2, RUB=0.14)

In [4]: df["new"] = df["NAM_CCY_SHORT"].map(xchg_rates) * df["AMT_FACE_VALUE"]
```

---

результат:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  NAM_CCY_SHORT  AMT_FACE_VALUE      new
0           TJS         12000.0  12000.0
1           USD          5000.0  51000.0
2           TJS          2000.0   2000.0
3           USD          2500.0  25500.0
4           TJS          8000.0   8000.0
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы настоящий профессионал:)